# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unparse')

Tags: vue.js, csv, papaparse

I installed `VuePapaParse`, but it seems like it's not working. What did I do wrong here?
I followed this documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-papa-parse

I am having error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unparse')

This is my code:

```
<script setup>
import VuePapaParse from 'vue-papa-parse'
</script>

<template>
     <FileUploader :onSubmit="onFileSubmit" />
     <br>

     <ButtonSubmit @click="CSVToJSON" :label="buttonLabel"/>
</template>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            file: null,
        }
    },
        watch: {
        unparsedResults (current) {
          if (current) {
            console.log(current)
          }
        }
      },
        
        methods: {
        
            onFileSubmit: async function(file) {
                this.file = file
                const reader = new FileReader();
    
                reader.readAsText(file);
    
                reader.onload = () => {
                    console.log(reader.result);
                    console.log(this.file)
                };
    
                reader.onerror = () => {
                    console.log(reader.error);
                };
            },
    
          CSVToJSON() {
            this.unparsedResults = this.$papa.unparse(this.file, {
              delimiter: ","
            })
          },
        },

</script>
```

Comment: You probably didn't install the plugin. Follow the `Default import` instructions as seen in the docs you linked.

Comment: your SFC is odd ... you have a `script setup` with just an import, then you have a `script` tag with what looks almost like vue options API, except for the fact that it's complete garbage